# varible not parsing from php function

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a unique String with a function. feed the output into a different function that checks a database with PDO to see if that String of characters already exists and then parse it to be entered into a database using PDO. IF for some reason the query comes up positive the function that generates the String gets called again and the process repeats itself. (   on a side  note this is why I need this to be done via functions; so I can recall the function over and over if I need to, if you have any better ideas please do share)

my `code`

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=notifiyr;charset=utf8mb4", 'root', '', [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);  

$length = 10;

function generatecode($length,$pdo){
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
    $abc = $randomString;
    checkcode($abc);
}

function checkcode($abc){
    $sql2 = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE code = :code";
    
    if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql2,$abc,$pdo)){
        $stmt->bindParam(":code", $param_code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $param_code = $abc;

        if($stmt->execute()){
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                generatecode();
            } else{
                $code = $abc;
            }
        } else{
            $code_err = "something doest want to work here, come back later";
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
        // Close statement
        unset($stmt);
    }
}
```

the problem I am having is that later on in the script I am supposed to enter this along with other variables into the database using PDO all of them enter but the randomly generated string.

**edit**

I changed my code to this

```
function generatecode($length,$pdo){
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
    $abc = $randomString;
    return $abc;
}

function checkcode($abc,$pdo){
    $sql2 = "SELECT code FROM users WHERE code = :code";
    
    if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql2,$abc,$pdo)){
        $stmt->bindParam(":code", $param_code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $param_code = $abc;

        if($stmt->execute()){
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                generatecode();
            } else{
                $code = $abc;
                return $code;
            }
        } else{
            $code_err = "something doest want to work here, come back later";
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }

        // Close statement
        unset($stmt);
    }
}
generatecode($length,$pdo);

checkcode($abc,$pdo);
```

I've had trouble returning functions before in PHP, I hope this code is better

Comment: Using functional programming is very appropriate. I’m not clear what is failing, but I did notice that you are not passing `$pdo` into `checkcode()`, so I wouldn’t expect your checking to be accurate; it probably always returns null. I would probably do away with the if clause around `$stmt = $pdo->prepare` and rely on catching exceptions instead. I trust the echo is for debugging; I’d ditch that when you’re done with it.

Comment: Don't rely on the output of a SELECT query to avoid inserting duplicates. In a multi-user system, another process could insert into the database between the time when your SELECT runs and your subsequent INSERT runs, and then you'll get duplicates. Instead, create a UNIQUE constraint on the field in question and then verify that your INSERT succeeded.

Comment: Also note that neither of these functions return anything, and the insert isn't happening inside them. So whatever code gets generated is lost once the function ends.

Comment: why don't they return anything? I'm really not got at functions withing PHP. @AlexHowansky

Comment: They don't return anything because they lack `return` statements. See the docs [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php).

Comment: @AlexHowansky I've tried that, didn't work. but I hope I'm closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using functions correctly, not only are you not parsing items incorrectly you are calling them incorrectly. read the documentation more carefully.

I think you would be want something like this

```
function generatecode($length,$pdo){
    $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
    $abc = $randomString;
    return checkcode($abc,$pdo);
}

function checkcode($abc,$pdo){
    $sql2 = "SELECT code FROM users WHERE code = :code";
    
    if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql2)){
        $stmt->bindParam(":code", $param_code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $param_code = $abc;

        if($stmt->execute()){
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                generatecode();
            } else{
                $code = $abc;
                return $code;
            }
        } else{
            $code_err = "something doest want to work here, come back later";
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }

        // Close statement
        unset($stmt);
    }
}

$code = generatecode($length,$pdo);// this correctly calls the function
```

you're welcome